# Creating a new list using for loop?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.5

I need to write a function that normalizes a vector (finds the unit vector). A vector can be normalized by dividing each individual component of the vector by its magnitude.

The input for this function will be a vector i.e. 1 dimensional list containing 3 integers.

The code follows:

```
def my_norml(my_list):
    tot_sum = 0
    for item in my_list:
        tot_sum = tot_sum + item**2
    magng = tot_sum**(1/2)
    norml1 = my_list[0]/magng #here i want to use a for loop 
    norml2 = my_list[1]/magng
    norml3 = my_list[2]/magng
    return [norml1, norml2,norml3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things you could do here.

Initially, let me just point out that `tot_sum = tot_sum + item**2` can be written more concisely as `tot_sum += item**2`. To answer your question, you could use a loop to achieve what you want with:

```
ret_list = []
for i in my_list:
    ret_list.append(i / magng)
return ret_list
```

But this isn't the best approach. *It is way better to utilize comprehensions* to achieve what you need; also, the `sum` built-in function can do summing for you instead of you needing to manually perform it with a `for-loop`:

`magng` can easily be computed in one line by passing a comprehension to `sum`. With the comprehension you raise each `item` to `** 2` and then immediately divide the summation that `sum` returns:

```
magng = sum(item**2 for item in my_list) ** (1/2)
```

After this, you can create your new list by again utilizing a comprehension:

```
return [item/magng for item in my_list]
```

Which creates a list out of every `item` in `my_list` after dividing it by `magng`.

Finally, your full function could be reduced to two lines (and one but that would hamper readability):

```
def my_norml(my_list):
    magng = sum(item**2 for item in my_list) ** (1/2)
    return [item/magng for item in my_list]
```

This is more concise and idiomatic and pretty intuitive too after you've learned comprehensions.